# RethinkDb without deep nested

Tags: rethinkdb

I would like to remove a sequence of objects 4 levels down, in this case I want to remove Level3

- Root

  - Level1

    - Level2

      - Level3

I am able to remove Level1 by using this logic
r.table("TableName").get("4045").without({'Root':'Level1'})
However if I specify
r.table("TableName").get("4045").without({'Root':'Level1':'Level2':'Level3'}) I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Please let me know how I can remove Level3.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a nested json object, so the correct syntax would be something like this:

```
r.table("TableName").get("4045").without({'Root':{'Level1':{'Level2':{'Level3':true}}}})
```

link to the documentation: https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/without